# Grepping number in a file

Tags: command-line, grep

I have this command

```
$ cut -f2,3 AIS2F1 | grep [2-9][0-9]*  | cut -f1
```

So my second and third fields are something like this

```
Ben 434
Me  12
you 56
```

So, I thought that the logic should be to cut the second and third field then grep numbers that are bigger than 20 and then cut the first field. That should give me the name that is on the same line with number that is bigger than 20, but it gives me this output:

```
Ben 
Me
you
```

instead of

```
Ben
you
```

which is what I want, how can I fix this command?

Comment: You need to quote your arguments to grep. That regex is also a valid shell glob, and could be expanded by the shell before grep sees it

Comment: Not an answer, but `awk` is better suited here as well: `awk '$3 ~ /[2-9][0-9]+/ { print $2 }' AIS2F1`

Comment: @jordanm, no need for `+` or `*` here. Also, looks like `awk '$3 >= 20 {print $2}` may be even  more appropriate here.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` in `grep` means that zero or one of the previous occurrences will be matches. Thus, your `grep` command matches every line containing a `[2-9]`. Replace the `*` with a `\+`, which means: match one or more occurrence.