# Search for number in text

Tags: bash, grep, text

I have a text file and I want so scan this text file for a specific number. Lets say the text file is:

```
asdg32dasdgdsa
dsagdssa11
adad 12345
dsaga
```

Now I want to search for a number with the length of 5 and print it out (`12345`).

How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Do you want a _specific_ number or all numbers with 5 digits? Also, how do you want to deal with decimals? Does `1.2345` have a length of 5 or 6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grepping number in a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67363/grepping-number-in-a-file)

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the `grep` command:

```
DESCRIPTION
   grep searches the named input FILEs for lines containing a match to the
   given PATTERN.  If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given,
   grep  searches  standard  input.   By default, grep prints the matching
   lines.
```

So, to find the number `12345`, run:

```
$ grep 12345 file
adad 12345
```

That will print all lines matching `12345`. To print only the matched portion of the line, use the `-o` flag:

```
$ grep -o 12345 file
12345
```

To find any stretch of consecutive digits of length 5, you can use one of:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' file
12345
$ grep -o '[0-9]\{5\}' file
12345
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]{5}' file 
12345
$ grep -Po '\d{5}' file 
12345
```

To do the same thing but ignore any numbers longer than 5 digits, use:

```
$ grep -Po '[^\d]\K[0-9]{5}[^\d]*' file
12345
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' file
```

Comment: This will also list any number with length greater than or equal 5

Comment: that's right ! but i answered according to the question form , however exist other good answers :)

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
tr -cs '[:digit:]' '[\n*]' <file | grep '^.\{5\}$'
```